# Vue3 where to implement my modal for a replicated component (child or parent)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Sorry still a bit new to Vue3
I have a contact component replicated multiple times with an edit button calling a modal to edit the contact and I was wondering if I should put my modal inside the contact component and thus replicate it as many times as I have contacts (10 at most) or if I should put my modal on the parent and call it from my child emiting the contact to edit.

The first method seems pretty simple to implement, and looks more logic to maintain my code but duplicates my modals in the final HTML, the second one looks more complicated since i need to emit to the parent the contact to modify (I think... ? still not really sure how to implement it so if someone can clarify) and not really logic to me since.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a separate component for your modal and put your component with the contact form in the default slot of your modal component.

Something like this:

```
<my-modal>
  <my-contact @submit="closeMyModal()">
  </my-contact>
</my-modal>
```

Here is the Doc about using [Slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#slots)

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a general component, [@unoverlays/vue](https://unoverlays.vercel.app/en/vue/) can help you

```html
<!-- overlay.vue -->
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue'
import { useOverlayMeta } from '@unoverlays/vue'
const props = defineProps({
  content: String,
})
// Get overlay information from useOverlayMeta
const { visible, resolve, reject } = useOverlayMeta({
  // Duration of the overlay animation to avoid premature component destruction
  animation: 1000,
})
</script>

<template>
  <!-- Customized modal using vuetify -->
  <v-dialog v-model="visible">
    <div>{{ content }}</div>

    <button @click="resolve(`${content}:confirmed`)"> click confirm </button>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

You can use the `defineOverlay/renderOverlay` method to convert the component into a modal dialog in Javascript / Typescript, which allows you to call it.

```
import { defineOverlay } from '@unoverlays/vue'
import OverlayComponent from './overlay.vue'

// Convert to imperative callback
const callback = defineOverlay(OverlayComponent)
// Call the component and get the value of the resolve callback
const value = await callback({ content: 'callbackOverlay' })
// value === "callbackOverlay:confirmed"
```